# Storing string values in array then displaying the array values

Tags: c#

I’m a student working on a class project to store string values into an array[10] using a “Store” button. Then the “Display” button will display the string values in the array[10] in a list box. Extra credit if we display the position too.

Currently when I click the “Store” button I do see the message the value was stored. But when I click the “Display” button the list box shows 10 “0”.  Every time I make it only makes it worse so I’m not sure what I’m missing and overlooking.

My global variables

```
string[] results = new string[10];
string value;
```

I’m using the for loop to take the string value in the “ResultLabel” to store them in the array[10] until all spaces are take, total of 10 values. The “StoreLabel” displays the message that the value was stored.

```
protected void StoreButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < results.Length; i++)
    {
        results[i] = ResultLabel.Text.ToString();
    }
    StoreLabel.Text = "Results have been stored";
}
```

Then I believe I’m taking the values from the results[10] array and displaying those values in the list box.

```
protected void DisplayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DisplayListBox.Items.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < results.Length; i++)
    {
        DisplayListBox.Items.Add(results[i].ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Windows Forms?

Comment: If your page is posting back, your array will be empty if you're working on asp.net web forms

Comment: Every time you click the `Store` button, you're setting all 10 elements of the array to what `ResultLabel` currently is. If you want to store the values one at a time, you'll need to track the index where the next value should be stored.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Windows Form for this project.

Comment: How would I set the array values to each entry into the results label instead of setting them all to zero? I have tried so many options I thought were correct but each one gave me different errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can append the index to string.

```
   private void StoreButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < results.Length; i++)
        {
            results[i] = ResultLabel.Text.ToString();
        }
        StoreLabel.Text = "Results have been stored";
    }

    private void DisplayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayListBox.Items.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < results.Length; i++)
        {
            DisplayListBox.Items.Add($"{results[i].ToString()} - {i}");
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand your project requires you to use an array and to limit it to 10 items. Those requirements might be simplified if we let the ListBox do all the hard work. I'd like to offer an easy way to get strings into the ListBox with the idea that you can then adapt this strategy to meet your project requirements.

The ListBox is simple to work with if we tell it to use our list as the source of the items it displays. Then all we have to do is add an item to this list and tell the ListBox to Refresh() its contents.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listBoxDisplay.DataSource = Values;
    }
    // Here is our list of strings
    BindingList<string> Values = new BindingList<string>();

    private void buttonStore_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // We look at the value in the textbox and add it to list...
        Values.Add((Values.Count + 1).ToString() + " - " +  textBoxValueToAdd.Text);

        // …and tell the ListBox to update itself from the list
        listBoxDisplay.Refresh();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the input, I certainly see value in what you're saying. However, I must use an array and display the array values in the list box or I don't receive the credit.

Comment: Understood! Thanks.